# confine rendering to cclayer frame

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way of confining the rendering of CCSprites and such onto a CCLayer in a way that anything beyond the frame of the CCLayer gets clipped (ie. doesn't display past the frame of the CCLayer)?

Why do I need this? I'm working on a roguelike and want a modal box to appear to select spells, wands, potions or scrolls.  I place a CCSCcrollView on top a CCLayer to scroll through the lists but I need to confine the display to just the region I want.

Comment: use a CCClippingNode to embed your menu ( I believe it is available starting cocos2d version 2.1) .

Comment: Unfortunately, I use version 1 or something, and have been developing this program for about 2 years, so switching to another version would be too much of a pain.

Comment: it is your trade-off : time/effort to update vs time/effort to figure-out this in your version. There are many advantages to upgrading.

Comment: Its okay, I found a ClippingNode class at http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/01/cocos2d-gem-clippingnode/ that will do the job, thanks